# How to use 'pagehide' event in safari to prevent unloading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, dom-events

I have a page where I send ajax requests after some users actions. It's important to wait when all these requests will finish before user leaves the page. To do this I set some state var before and after ajax request and watch it in `beforeunload` event handler:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', lockUnloadAction.bind(this));
}
...
export function lockUnloadAction(event) {
    let returnText = undefined;
    if (this.state.isRequestProgress) {
        // send to GA
        ....
        returnText = 'На странице еще выполняется отправка сообщения. ' +
            'Вы уверены, что хотите уйти со страницы?';
        event.returnValue = returnText;
    }

    return returnText;
}
```

But in Safari `beforeunload` is not working. According to documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5 I should use `pagehide`.

But any confirm, alert are not allowed inside this event handler (I get error in console 'window.alert is not allowed while unloading page'). I tried also use `preventDefault()` or `stopPropogation` and then alert or confirm, also I tried return some text value and set `event.returnValue` like for `beforeunload` event handler. Nothing helped.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('pagehide', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        confirm('someText');
        event.returnValue = 'someText';
        return 'someText'
    );
}
```

Is there any other way to prevent unloading page with confirmation in Safari and mobile Safari or I should use `pagehide` by another way?

Answer (score 2):

according to [these MDN specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event), the pagehide event is not cancelable